# Undefined props in Vue 2

Tags: vuejs2

Despite of the amount of threads on the subject i can't figure out my mistake and why my 'props' stays undefined in my map-component.

Here is the root instance:

```
import Vue from "vue/dist/vue.esm.js";
import mapComponent from "./map-component.vue";

let vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `
  <map-component> v-bind:feature-collection="featureCollection" </map-component>
  `,
  components: {
    mapComponent
  },
  data: {
    featureCollection: {
      type: "FeatureCollection",
      features: [
        {
          type: "Feature",
          properties: {},
          geometry: {
            type: "Polygon",
            coordinates: [
              [
                [14.501953124999998, 46.619261036171515],
                [21.884765625, 46.619261036171515],
                [21.884765625, 48.922499263758255],
                [14.501953124999998, 48.922499263758255],
                [14.501953124999998, 46.619261036171515]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

and my map-component:

```
<template>
<div id="map-placeholder">
    <div ref="mapContainer" class="map-container"></div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet.markercluster";

export default {
  name: "map-component",
  data() {
    return {
      map: null,
      markers: null,
      tileLayer: null,
      layers: null
    };
  },
  props: [ "featureCollection" ],
  methods: { ... },
  mounted() {
    this.initMap();
    this.initLayer();
    this.addLocationGeoJson("observation",this.featureCollection.features)
  }
};
</script>
```

The script fails at `this.addLocationGeoJson("observation",this.featureCollection.features)` since `featureCollection` is undefined. 
Full code available [here](https://github.com/charlycou/components-vjs).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<map-component> v-bind:feature-collection="featureCollection" </map-component>`

Check where your tags open and close.

It should be: `<map-component v-bind:feature-collection="featureCollection">`

Comment: Thanks! While trying to understand I went through this: [link](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f). From your point of view, is it a good practice to use `props` in `mounted` life cycle hook?